# Select rows not in another table by comparing two table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following two tables **TableA** and **TableB**

**TableA**

```
Id  Month_Id    Customer_Id   Total_Amount
1    1          1               50
2    2          1              150
3    3          1              200
4    1          2               75
5    2          2              100
6    1          3              400
7    2          3              200
```

**TableB**

```
Id  Month_Id    Customer_Id         Total_Amount
1     1               1             50
2     2               1            150
3     1               2             75
```

I want to compare **Month_Id**  **Customer_Id**  **Total_Amount** in both tables and select **Id** from **TableA**. The output should be as follow.

**Output**

```
Id
3
5
6
7
```

My concept is:

```
SELECT TableA.Id FROM TableA 
WHERE TableA.Month_Id <> TableB.MonthId AND
TableA.Customer_Id <> TableB.Customer_Id AND
TableA.Total_Amount <> TableB.Total_Amount
```

Comment: What is your code so far?

Comment: Compare how and return what? Like match equal amounts in same month for same user and return rows that does not have a matching pair in the other table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT TableA.Id
    FROM TableA
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM TableB
      WHERE TableB.Month_Id = TableA.Month_Id
      AND TableB.Customer_Id = TableA.Customer_Id
      AND TableB.Total_Amount = TableA.Total_Amount
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select Id 
from (
select Id, Month_Id,    Customer_Id,   Total_Amount from TableA    
except     
select Id, Month_Id,    Customer_Id,   Total_Amount from TableB
) q
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id FROM
     (SELECT id, month_id, customer_id, total_ammount FROM TableA
      EXCEPT    
      SELECT id, month_id, customer_id, total_ammount FROM TableB);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `EXCEPT` set operator:

```
SELECT id 
FROM   (SELECT * FROM table_a
        EXCEPT
        SELECT * FROM table_b) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) with  `WHEN NOT MATCHED`

place your condition in  `ON <merge_search_condition>`

Answer (score 0):

In oracle sql it would be:

```
SELECT ID FROM
   (SELECT ID, Month_Id, Customer_Id, Total_Amount FROM TABLE_A
    MINUS 
    SELECT ID, Month_Id, Customer_Id, Total_Amount FROM TABLE_B);
```

Is this what you want?
(Not sure of MINUS operator in sql-server though)

Comment: There's indeed no `MINUS` operator in SQL Server. The equivalent there is  `EXCEPT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id FROM TableA A LEFT JOIN tableB B 
    ON  A.Id=B.Id AND A.Month_Id =B.Month_Id  
    AND A.Customer_Id   =B.Customer_Id  
    AND A.Total_Amount=b.Total_Amount
WHERE B.Id is NULL
```

Comment: Just a few words what was wrong and how your code solves that woukd make this a better answer